# Weighted score of a multiple-choice option with more than one answer

Tags: algorithm, math, scoring, multiple-choice, weighted-average

What would be the formula to calculate the weighted score for the following scenario?

Some question is asked with answer scores ranging from 0 to 5. No correct or incorrect classification. Just a relative score range.

- Answer 1 Weight = 5
- Answer 2 Weight = 4
- Answer 3 Weight = 0

**Choice Scenarios:**

1. Highest score if both 1 & 2 are chosen.
2. Lower score if all 3 options are chosen
3. Worst score on the choice of 3.
4. Good (but not the maximum) score if either 1 or 2 is chosen.

I also thought about making the scale -5 to 5 in order to penalize for choosing a negative weight.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: Thanks Stark for the prompt answer. I am actually working on a training and evaluation software. The evaluator will configure the system such that the user will be presented with a number of choices for a particular scenario. Each choice will have a weight ranging from worst to best [e.g. 0 to 5]. Final cumulative score will be calculated by taking a weighted sum of individual scores of all the scenarios based on the choices made by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avg weight is 3, score = sum(weight[answers] - avg).

```
Choose 1, score = 2
Choose 2, score = 1
Choose 1 & 2, score = 3
Choose 1, 2 & 3, score = 0
Choose 3, score = -3
```

Comment: How can we calculate the range of possible scores [Min, Max]?

Comment: I have observed the following about this formula: 1) Always returns zero if all or no choice is made. In other words, if the user makes no selection, his score will be better than the worst score. 2) All answers with weight higher than average contribute positively whereas the others contribute negatively to the calculated score.

Comment: Min score would be all answers below the average. Max score would be all answers above the average.  Answers equal to the average don't matter since they don't contribute to the score.